# I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error when trying to convert current month number to current month name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

In the project, I want to write down the current day and month like this:

```
Today is the 13th of September
```

When getting the current day, there is no error. But, when converting the current month number to the current month name, I get the error below:

```
Date.jsx:4 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

My code in the Date component:

```
function Date() {
  let date = new Date()
  // console.log(dayDate.getDate())

  const takeMonth = (month) => {
    const monthName = date.setMonth(month - 1)
    return monthName.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" })
  }
  return <div> Date {takeMonth(3)}</div>
}
```

All answers are appreciated!

Comment: You created a function with the same name as the Date object of JavaScript.
So instead of creating a Date object you are calling the function recursively and that's why the error.

Comment: Exactly what @Xion14 said. Just changed the name of your function to something other than Date as it is a reserved keyword within Javascript.

Comment: @dabyland Not really a reserved keyword. It is just a property of the global object,
you can still access it with "window.Date" or whatever is the global object in each enviroment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently overriding the `Date` function by defining your own function called `Date`, so when you call `new Date()` inside your function, you are in fact calling your own override, which creates an infinite loop...

You should rename your own function like:

```js
function getDate() {
  let date = new Date()
  /* rest of the code */
}
```